# Search function with similarity function

Tags: php, mysql, search

The table name is 'pages'..

I need to make a search function, where I can submit the field $_POST['search']['s_value'] and check if it is LIKE the fields 'emne' or 'tekst'..

But in that matter I would also like, that my query is ordering by the percentage of matching.. So if I'm searching for "car rental" and I have a page which say "car rental has been easier over the past years" it is 100%.

If it is possible, I would also like the search to make a 'teaser' with the first match of the text, where it is highlighted in a div with the class='search_highligthed_text' ..

Is that in any way possible to create???

Comment: Have you even tried to do this yourself?

Comment: I first tried to do this with a normal php-script where I dumped all rows to an array and put their similar_text()-value in another array, but I got problems when I needed to make paging of the results.
Afterwards I tried the MATCH-function in MySQL, but I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i cannot undertand the problem with similar_text(); why don't you just put data in an array an than sort them?

Comment: OP is looking for a way to select MySQL results based on similarity; `similar_text()` is a PHP function and can only be applied _after_ you've retrieved the data. If OP wants to display _all_ the data, you can use the PHP function, but I'm betting he only wants to retrieve e.g. everything that's a 90 to 100% match.

Comment: No I actually just want to page them - with 15 hits pr. page sorted by the percentage of similarity (desc)..

Comment: In this case you can do it with PHP. Put your data in a session array (if you use a framework eg ZendFramework there sould be better way to manipulate session), sort it and the trick is done!

Comment: I have made it work with some arrays - if you want to see the solution, then try and write me.